# for loop in while (building matrix)

Tags: c++, for-loop, matrix, do-while

It builts each number[i][j] of matrix and after every number it checks by comparing the number[i][j] with the numbers[k][l] before it.

At first it passes because of not having numbers before.

Real goal is to make a matrix with all different numbers.
I'm trying to return start of checking the numbers of matrix so that at any encounter of beeing same it will restart checking.

(it changes numbers if any are same. After changing, the number which is changed can be same with anyone at start of matrix too so i want check again at any change)

```
int matris[10][10];

int counter = 0;

bool control = true;

for (int i = 0; i<10; i++) {

    for (int j = 0; j<10; j++) {

        matris[i][j] = rand() % 99;
        do {
            for (int k = 0; k <= i; k++) {

                for (int l = 0; l <= j; l++) {
                    if (matris[i][j] == matris[k][l])
                    {
                        matris[i][j] = rand() % 99;
                        counter++;
                       if(k==i&&l==j)break;
                        control = false;
                    } 
                     else control=true;

                }

            }

        } while (control == false);

    }

}
```

It is not important if values it writes is 99-0 or 100-1.My teacher asked us for numbers between 100-1.

The real problem is it doesn't control back with while.It sometimes gives same numbers.It should't.

counter = how many times do numbers changed.

Here results..

counter:124
Matrix:
  54  68  83  55  12  30  97  96  63  91
  52  55   8   6  96  46  55  14  65  93
  52  94  39   6  92  40  12  86  66  61
  11  33  77  46  97   6  16  28  28  46
  17  72  16  75  93  81  61  82  34  19
  93  72  96  34  48  49  29  54  81  94
  72  27  13   8  22  52  12  96  35  66
  87  84  79  10  52  24  45  49  82  48
  32  64  34  32  82  85  70  72  97  55
  44  93   9  86  10   4  33  25  32  99

You can see if there are same numbers, there it's ranked.
  99  97  97  97  96  96  96  96  94  94
  93  93  93  93  92  91  87  86  86  85
  84  83  82  82  82  81  81  79  77  75
  72  72  72  72  70  68  66  66  65  64
  63  61  61  55  55  55  55  54  54  52
  52  52  52  49  49  48  48  46  46  46
  45  44  40  39  35  34  34  34  33  33
  32  32  32  30  29  28  28  27  25  24
  22  19  17  16  16  14  13  12  12  12
  11  10  10   9   8   8   6   6   6   4
Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: You are trying to assign 99 unique values 100 ways. The last cell can't possibly find a random value that hasn't been assigned.

Comment: Because "kontrol" is always false after the first iteration.

Comment: Consider: create a list of the numbers 1 through 100. Randomly select one of these numbers, assign it to your matrix, and remove the number from the list. Randomly select another number from the list, assign it to the matrix, and remove it. Repeat until matrix is full. Variant of the [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle).

Comment: You are not searching all assigned values in your inner loop. Imagine when `i = 1` and `j = 1`. You will only compare the new value with `[0][0]` but you've assigned values to the elements `[0][0]` to `[0][9]`.

Comment: Here im actually trying to understand why doesnt do-while work well.I accept that matrix can be built with a way better.

Comment: In short, it just doesn't work unless you try `rand()%100` (add `+1` or `+100` if you like), as `rand()%99` can only generate 99 unique values instead of 100. It's not your `do-while` that doesn't work well. Even still, assuming your code is guaranteed to finish it will probably take a very long time.

Answer (score 0):

Actually do-while works well but inside it you are using for `(int k = 0; k < i; k++)` which iterates up to `i-1` and say if you put your 6th element in your matrix you are only checking up to 5th element and skipping the 6th one. you may try `(int k = 0; k < i+1; k++)` instead.

Another approach is if you want all numbers 0-99 in your matrix put them in first then scramble the matrix by randomly swapping locations... this should do the trick.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int matris[10][10];
    int sayac = 0;

    // put all of them in first
    for (int i = 0; i<10; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j<10; j++) {
            matris[i][j] = sayac;
            sayac++;
        }
    }

    // then scramble
    for (int i = 0; i<10; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j<10; j++) {
            int tmp,k ,l;
            k = rand()%9;
            l = rand()%9;
            tmp = matris[i][j];
            matris[i][j] = matris[k][l];
            matris[k][l] = tmp;
        }
    }

    // check the result
    for (int i = 0; i<10; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            cout << matris[i][j] << "\t";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

to see different results each time you need to use `rand()`  function with a seed which is usually the system clock.

Comment: Logic of k<i and l<k is to compare last number with numbers before.             
It already seeds with rand()in 2. for loop.

Comment: think that i=6,j=6  - you have 6 rows filled (all 10 columns) and on 7th row on 7th column now and put the 67th element; inner loop k<i = k<6 which is up to 5 and same for l<6 which is checking top left 6*6 = 36 elements only !!! you can try it on paper...

Comment: On the other hand rand() function is  a pseudo random function, what I meant is you should use srand() instead.

Comment: Well!. It helped, counter increased.But there are still same numbers.

Comment: It doesnt have to be different in each code.That is what srand() is for. I need the numbers different just in 1 compilation its ok.